# How to align on the page two appended childes, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create two tables, append them to the page.

When i am just appending two tables:

```
document.getElementById("list").appendChild(list_table_one);
document.getElementById("list").appendChild(list_table_two);
```

They placed on page one under another.
How i can put them side by side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Setting the table's `display` property to `inline-block`](http://jsfiddle.net/WB8nR/1/), or [`float`ing the table to one side](http://jsfiddle.net/WB8nR/) should allow them to display side-by-side, assuming they are narrow enough.

```
table {
    display: inline-block;
    /* or */
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the diplay propert to inline-block

See [the example](http://jsbin.com/UGerub/3/edit?html,css,output) for more details

**UPDATE:** I add table to show how to configure the css to break lines.

It's important to say that those elements are inside a div, that have a defined width.

Comment: table moved to center, but they still in same position

Comment: as I show on example, I put those two elements inside a div, and I set this div with fixed width.

Comment: @GudronSwiss If this isn't working, you should show an example of your page structure - setting a table to display as an `inline-block` element should work properly.